# chart.js line chart update once every 5 seconds?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, chart.js

I know there are few methods to update/refresh chart data on chart.js line Chart, but i am not rendering the chart directly to the webpage

let say the chart.js line chart is on page0 ,i am using iframe to show the page0 on page1 and then calling page1 in an iframe on page2
. I know this is not the optimal way to do it but there are some reasons i need to do it this way.

chart.js on page0 is reading the data from a csv file to draw line chart ,now the problem is that csv keep getting updated every minute and i need the chart on page2 to be updated as well, i tried refreshing the iframe on page2 but it isnt exactly suitable in my case, since its reloading the page again and again, is there any other way to update the lines as the new data arrives , or maybe update the line once evey 5 seconds or so ?

**Page0 code thats drawing the line chart using csv:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <canvas id="myChart" width="500" height="200"></canvas>
    <script>
      const makeChart = async () => {
        const ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
        const csvData = await getData();
        const { dataLabels, columnFive, columnSix } = csvData;
        const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
          type: "line",
          data: {
            labels: dataLabels,
            datasets: [
              {
                label: "Long Positions",
                data: columnFive,
                fill: false,
                borderColor: "green",
         pointRadius: 0,

              },
              {
                label: "Short Positions",
                data: columnSix,
                fill: false,
                borderColor: "red",
        pointRadius: 0,
          gridLines: {
                lineWidth: 0
            }
              },
            ],
          },
        });
      };
      window.addEventListener("load", makeChart);

      const getData = async () => {
        const data = await fetch("./myfile.csv").then((res) => res.text());
        const dataLabels = [];
        const columnFive = [];
        const columnSix = [];
        const rows = data.split("\n");
        rows.map((row) => {
          const cols = row.split(",");
          dataLabels.push(cols[0]);
          columnFive.push(parseFloat(cols[5]));
          columnSix.push(parseFloat(cols[6]));
        });
        return { dataLabels, columnFive, columnSix };
      };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Page 1 Code thats using iframe to to show the chart(its also rendering the trading view widget ): **

```
<html>
  <head>






<script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/tv.js"></script>
    <script>
    function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) {
      url = window.location.href;
    }
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
var fx = getParameterByName('value');
      var fxWidget = new TradingView.widget({
      "width": 410,
      "height": 280,
      "symbol": "FX:"+fx,
      "interval": "1",
      "timezone": "Etc/UTC",
      "theme": "White",
      "style": "1",
      "locale": "en",
      "toolbar_bg": "#f1f3f6",
      "hide_top_toolbar": true,
      "save_image": false,
      "hideideas": true
    }); 

 
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
<select id="check">
  <option value="Lot">Lot</option>
  <option value="Position">Position</option>
</select>

<iframe id="showskill" scrolling="no" height="35%" width ="100%" src=""></iframe>


<script>
   
</script>
<script>


document.getElementById('check').addEventListener('change', function() {
  if (this.value=="Lot")
{var str1 = "http://localhost:45480/";
var str2 = fx;
var strr = "L"
var rest = str2.concat(strr);
var res = str1.concat(rest);
var str3 = ".html";
var str4 = res.concat(str3);
console.log(str4);
 document.getElementById("showskill").src =str4;
}
if (this.value=="Position")
{var str1 = "http://localhost:45480/";
var str2 = fx;
var strr = "P"
var rest = str2.concat(strr);
var res = str1.concat(rest);
var str3 = ".html";
var str4 = res.concat(str3);
console.log(str4);
 document.getElementById("showskill").src =str4;
}
});
</script>

  </body>
</html>
```

**Page2 thats using the iframe to call page 1**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="column"  >
   
   <select name="fx" class="fx">
    <option value="EURUSD">EURUSD</option>
    <option value="EURJPY">EURJPY</option>
    <option value="EURGBP">EURGBP</option>
    <option value="EURCAD">EURCAD</option>
    <option value="GBPUSD">GBPUSD</option>
    <option value="EURAUD">EURAUD</option>
    <option value="GBPJPY">GBPJPY</option>
    <option value="GBPCAD">GBPCAD</option>
    <option value="GBPAUD">GBPAUD</option>
    <option value="GBPCHF">GBPCHF</option>
</select>
<iframe src="chart1.html"   id="content" >
```

Comment: it will be difficult to help you without your html,js,css code. I suggest you to create a snippet  with a functional sample

Comment: @Frenchy there is so much code that i dont even know where to begin... is it okay if i add the html files as they are ?

Comment: it will be easier to people to help you if you have a similary sample functional..its difficult to bring an answer on only verbal (sorry for my english)

Comment: yeah i understand i was asking for the "impossible" without posting the code 
i updated the OP tried to make it as simpler as possible hope it makes sense

Comment: so how do you know the data of csv file are changed? when the new data arrive?

Comment: new data arrives once every minute , meaning when time is hh:mm:01 then the data is written on the csv , i am actually using a python program to make api calls and then parse and save received response into the csv file , it saves the data to the csv on start of every new minute

Comment: so in your html, you dont know when the csv is changed?

Comment: no , not in the html , if its not possible to update when new data arrives then the second best option would be to auto update the chart once every 5 seconds, but i dont know if its even possible or not

Answer (score 0):

one way to reload your csv file is to play with setInterval:

```
var timer = setInterval(function(){ makeChart;}, 60000);//execute makeChart every min
```

then you reload your widget  (i dont see how data arrives in the widget)

if you need to stop the loop, use:

```
clearInterval(timer);//stops the loop
```

Comment: so in this particular solution the chart will get automatically get updated on the page2 which is using the iframe to call the chart ? even without having to refresh it on page2?

Comment: instead to refresh the page, you rebuild the chart, but i dont see the link between page0 and page 2. (chart1.html is page 0?).test and say me

Comment: so yes chart1.html is updated when you recreate the chart, but not reloaded