# Display dynamic values from mysql with chart.js

Tags: php, mysql, charts, chart.js

Preliminary I am quite new to JS and php (since Monday). I have a database where I store data at certain time intervals. With chart.js I want to visualize this data, static no problem:

```
<?php

$username = "root";
$password = "_!Stud3nt&";
$database = "datalog";

try {
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;database=$database", $username, $password);
    //SET the PDO error mode to exception
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}   catch(PDOException $e){
    die("ERROR: could not connect. " . $e->getMessage());
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css">
    
    <title>ems</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .chartBox {
            width: 700px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
    <?php
    //Attempt select query execution
    try{
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM datalog.day_avg ORDER BY dateavg DESC LIMIT 7";
        $result = $pdo->query($sql);
        if($result->rowCount() > 0){
            $druck = array();
            $volumenstrom = array();
            $spannung = array();
            while($row=$result->fetch()){
                $druck[] = $row ["avg_druck"];
                $volumenstrom[] = $row ["avg_volumenstrom"];
                $spannung[] = $row ["avg_spannung_quelle"];
            }
        unset($result);
        }else{
            echo "No records matching your query were found.";
        }
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        die("ERROR: Not able to execute $sql.".$e->getMessage());
    }   
    //Close connection
    unset($pdo);
    ?>

    <div class="chartBox">
        <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
    </div>
    <script> </script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
    <script>

    //Setup Block

    const druck = <?php echo json_encode ($druck); ?>;
    const volumenstrom = <?php echo json_encode ($volumenstrom); ?>;
    const spannung = <?php echo json_encode ($spannung); ?>;
    const data = {
    labels: ['t-8', 't-7', 't-6', 't-5', 't-4', 't-3', 't-2', 't-1'], 
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Druck in bar',
                data: druck,
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                borderColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                borderWidth: 1
            },{
                label: 'Volumenstrom in l/min',
                data: volumenstrom,
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                borderColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                borderWidth: 1
            },{
            label: 'Spannung in V',
                data: spannung,
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                borderColor: 'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                borderWidth: 1
            }]
        };
    //Config Block
    const config = {

        type: 'line',
        data,
        options: {
            scales: {
                y: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }
        }
    };
    //Render Block
    const myChart = new Chart(
        document.getElementById('myChart'),
        config 
    );
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

But how is it possible to make the display dynamic with a few simple steps, e.g. that the graph is updated every second?

Because of the animation, the meta-tag doesn't seem to me to be such a good solution.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5">
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: You can do the refreshing inside Javascript, using [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started) to get the data from PHP. AJAX can be a somewhat daunting technique to use, but there's a lot of code out there to make it simpler. I personally still like to use [JQuery](https://jquery.com/), but it can be done with "pure" Javascript nowadays.

Comment: [chart.js line chart update once every 5 seconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66657722/2943403)

Comment: Thank you. I'll give it a try with JQuery :)